# 2012 Volvo V60 D3 keeps blowing low beam lamps

Tags: electrical, headlight, volvo

I am in South Africa and have a V60 D3 Volvo.

I keep on blowing the low beam bulbs.  Replaced both in a pair with good quality bulbs (did not touch them during installation).

At first they worked, then one goes dead. If you cycle the switch off and on, it turns back on again. After 2 weeks, it does not come on again. The right one lasted longer.

It started to do the same thing (not turn on). When I cycle the switch off and on again, it works. Now both are dead.

Do you have any advice for me? I have replaced about 6 sets of bulbs already and can not find the fault.

Comment: Could it be overvoltage?

Comment: If its overvoltage then you would probably have many more problems with your car. Do you use the same brand and type of bulbs each time?